# Can't update data automatically in angular 5

Tags: angular, forms, splice

I have a function to delete one row from a dataRows in a tableData. It works in the template but the data seems not to be deleted. Because when I use the "add a row button", there will appear one new line with the datas which I inputted before.

```
  deleteTicket(rowIndex: number): void {
    this.tableData2.dataRows.splice(rowIndex, 1);
  }
```

add method

```
<button mat-raised-button class="btn btn-just-icon btn-link" (click)="deleteTicket(i)" ></button>
```

template code

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of tableData2.dataRows; let i = index"><...><tr>
```

Anyone know how to delete the datas in the array?

Comment: Can you provide your add row method and the template code

Comment: I added the method and template code. Thank you.

Comment: Try this:   remove(row){  
    this.tableData2.dataRows=this.tableData2.dataRows.filter(item=>item!== row)
  }

Answer (score 1):

If tableData2 is an array ex.

this.tableData2 = [{name: "A" , value: 1}, {name: "B" , value: 1}, {name: "C" , value: 1}, {name: "D" , value: 1}]

Method should be ,

```
deleteTicket(rowIndex: number): void {
this.tableData2.splice(rowIndex, 1);
```

}

Comment: Thank you. But my array is like this: declare interface TableData {
  headerRow: string[];
  dataRows: string[][];
}

Comment: Can you give example of your array ?